# how to add headers to http packet in python?

Tags: python, http, header

so I have wrote this code which sends a picture to browser in http protocol. I want to add headers to that response but I have no idea how, I could not have found a proper solution on the internet.

```
import socket
file_to_return = open(r"C:\Users\hadad\Desktop\webroot\imgs\abstract.jpg", 'rb')
file_content = file_to_return.read()
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 80))
server_socket.listen()
client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
client_socket.send(file_content)
```

for example I want to add: "my header: some information"
so when I snuff my packet I can see it appear

Comment: The HTTP protocol is really complex. To be compliant, use a library.

Comment: With sockets you are sending data directly. So you have to setup the complete response, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228882/what-is-content-data-format-of-http-response-when-content-type-header-is-image-j

Comment: how can I code it? @ivvija

Comment: how can I make it work?